# How to disable tabbing in a tab panel in gwt

Tags: gwt, tabpanel

I have a tab panel in the gwt. I want allow the user to select the tab only by mouse. For this one I have disable the tabindex for all the tab in my tabpanle. I tried with this code:

```
DOM.setElementAttribute(cdrMeseTabPanel.getElement(), "tabIndex", "-1" );
```

but it is not working.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the tabIndex to an empty property:

```
DOM.setElementAttribute(cdrMeseTabPanel.getElement(), "tabIndex", "" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the tab index complemetely it worked for me.